# Laptop with 1 audio jack and headset with 2 seperate cables?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, microphone, headset

I have a laptop, but my laptop have only one audio jack.

**So i would like to know and ask, is it possible to connect ONLY the microphone from the headset to the audio jack on my laptop and speaking through it (because the microphone of the laptop makes lazy noise to the others that listening to me, and to listen from the speakrs of my laptop.. ?**

Till now i tried to connect it but i didn't get anything... just when i put the cable from my headset of the microphone into the audio jack.. the sound of my laptop speakers turns off, like i connected the headphone jack for headphones (speakers)... but i didn't, i connected the microphone cable from my headset and yet nothing... i tried like that , but still nothing...

Any idea how to fix this "To listen through my laptop speakrs and to speak through my HEADSET MICROPHONE?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Your laptop has only 1 AUDIO JACK. This is not a microphone jack. Yes the jacks look the same, but they have 2 completly different functions. One outputs audio (green, to speakers) and one inputs audio (pink, from microphone).

What you're looking for is to get something like this for your laptop, as long as your laptop does indeed have USB slots.

[image]